# Assign a variable to a property and modify the real object in QML

Tags: javascript, c++, qt, pointers, qml

I created quite a complicated UI structure. The type `bool` is here just as an example

```
Complicated
{
    property bool object
    function modify() { object = true }
    // complicated and long stuff here
}
```

And I put it into the UI like this (`myvar` is some boolean variable, say, exposed from C++ and `myvar == false`)

```
Column
{
    // some UI elements
    Complicated { id: comp; object: myvar }
    // more UI elements
}
```

1. Nothing has happened yet, so still `myvar == false`
2. `comp.modify()` is called
3. Now `comp.object == true` but `myvar == false`

What should I do so that `comp.modify()` modifies `myvar`? In C++ I'd use pointers, but there are no pointers in QML/JS? I'm using Qt5

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two-way binding out-of-the-box is still an unresolved issue:

[Need two-way Binding support as alternative to alias](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-19892)

See also the duplicate of that report:

[Allow creating two way bindings in QML](https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-21558)

You can find a "workaround" on Jira, but it is suboptimal. Basiaally, there are two workarounds:

- alias, but it is "hard", not "soft", which means it cannot be broken up.
- two-way Binding component usage, but it is breaking a reusable component and it is also tiresome to create two components forth and back.

In your specific case, probably the latter applies as myvar is not quite an alias. Try this out:

```
Binding {
    target: myCppClass
    property: "myvar" value: comp.object
    when: comp.completed
}
```

Comment: To avoid a binding loop, property has to be set in Component.onCompleted: `Complicated { id: comp; Component.onCompleted: { comp.object = myCppObject.myvar;  /* comp.completed = true */ } ; Binding { target: myCppObject; property: "myvar"; value: comp.object; /*when: comp.completed */ }
}`. How to properly handle this? I could uncomment the commented parts, but it's not an elegant solution.

Comment: Updated the answer with the workaround that I would use until it is resolved properly upstream.